# $f(S)=S^{-1}$ is continuous where $S:E\rightarrow E$ is an isomorphism between Banach spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $E$ be a Banach Space and $f:Iso(E,E)\rightarrow Iso(E,E)$ be given by $f(S)=S^{-1}$. Prove that $f$ is continuos.
>
> **Hint:** $f(I-T)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$ if $\lVert T\rVert<1$.

I was able to solve this without the hint as follows:

$$\lVert S^{-1}-S_o^{-1}\rVert=\lVert S^{-1}S_oS_o^{-1}-S_o^{-1} \rVert\leq \lVert S^{-1}S_o-I \rVert \lVert S_o^{-1} \rVert \leq  \lVert S^{-1}S_o-S^{-1} S \rVert \lVert S_o^{-1} \rVert\Rightarrow $$
$$\lVert  S^{-1}-S_o^{-1}\rVert\leq \lVert S^{-1}\rVert\lVert S_o^{-1}\rVert\lVert S-S_o\rVert$$

So we need to find a nice bound for $\lVert S^{-1} \rVert$. At first I noticed:

$$\lVert S^{-1} \rVert=\sup_{x\not=0}\frac{\lVert S^{-1}(x)\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}=\sup_{v\not=0}\frac{\lVert S^{-1}(S(v))\rVert}{\lVert S(v)\rVert}=\sup_{v\not=0}\frac{\lVert v\rVert}{\lVert S(v)\rVert}=$$
$$\left(\inf_{v\not=0}\frac{\lVert S(v)\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\inf_{\lVert v\rVert =1}\lVert S(v)\rVert}$$

It is straightforward to see that for $\lVert v \rVert=1$:

$$\lVert S (v) \rVert\geq \lVert S_o(v)-(S_o-S) (v) \rVert \geq\lVert S_o(v) \rVert-\lVert S-S_o\rVert\Rightarrow$$

$$ \inf_{\lVert v\rVert=1}\lVert S (v) \rVert \geq \inf_{\lVert v\rVert=1}\lVert S_o (v) \rVert - \lVert S-S_o\rVert\Rightarrow$$

$$ \frac{1}{\lVert S^{-1} \rVert} \geq \frac{1}{\lVert S_o^{-1}\rVert} - \lVert S-S_o\rVert\Rightarrow\lVert S^{-1}\rVert\leq \frac{\lVert S_{o}^{-1}\rVert}{1-\lVert S_o-S \rVert\lVert S_o^{-1}\rVert}$$

Combining this bound for $S$ with our initial inequality yields:

$$\rVert S^{-1}- S_o^{-1} \rVert \leq  \lVert S_o- S \rVert\lVert  S^{-1}\rVert \lVert S_o^{-1} \rVert\leq \frac{\lVert S_{o}^{-1}\rVert^2\lVert S-S_o \rVert}{1-\lVert S_o-S \rVert\lVert S_o^{-1}\rVert}$$

And from this it is clear that if $S\in Iso(E,E)$ and $\rVert S- S_o \rVert\leq \delta(\varepsilon)\Rightarrow \rVert S^{-1}- S_o^{-1} \rVert\leq\varepsilon$.

**I wonder how the hint comes into play and if my proof avoiding the hint is correct.**

Comment: According to me your proof is correct. (+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $f$ is continuous at $I.$ Indeed, when $S\to S_0$ then $SS_0^{-1}\to I.$ By the continuity at $I,$ we get $S_0S^{-1}\to I,$ thus $S^{-1}\to S_0^{-1}.$

So it remains to prove the continuity at $I.$ Let $S\to I.$ Denote $T=I-S.$ Assume $\|T\|<1.$ **Applying  the hint** gives $$S^{-1}-I=(I-T)^{-1}-I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty T^n$$ Thus $$\|S^{-1}-I\|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|T\|^n={\|T\|\over 1-\|T\|}={\|I-S\|\over 1-\|I-S\|}$$

**Remark** The advantage of this approach is that it can be applied to any Banach algebra. The elements do not need to be operators acting on some space.

Comment: It is very nice that our upper bounds coincide when $S_o=I$. Thank you for your very neat proof.

Comment: Thanks, also for accepting. Indeed the estimates coincide. There is another little advantage of the proof above. If $\|S-S_0\|<\|S_0^{-1}\|$ then $S$ is invertible, because, by the hint $SS_0^{-1}$ is invertible. Your proof, with $\inf$ gives that if $S$ is close to $S_0,$ then $S$ is injective and has closed range ($\|Sv\|\ge c\|v\|$). But it does not imply invertibility. You have to use that assumption, as you do not get it for free.

Comment: Do you mean $\lVert S-S_o \rVert\leq \lVert S_o^{-1} \rVert^{-1}$? How nice that being close to an invertible operator means it must be invertible! I was thinking of taking $S\in B(S_o, \delta)\cap Iso(E,E)$ and perhaps I should have made it explicit (nice catch!), but you are saying this intersection isn’t necessary because for $\delta$ small enough $B(S_o,\delta)\subset Iso(E,E)$. This is very surprising (to me)!  Very enlightening comment.